# Models associated with one another create undefined methods in Rails 5 undefined method `shoutouts' for #<User:0x007fd825472cf0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Was using Michael Harti's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts) and when following it I get an undefined method between two models. I have renamed the models and tried playing around a lot with it but all attempts end up with undefined methods or an uninitialized constant.

Shout Out controller

```
class ShoutOutController < ApplicationController

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @shout_out = current_user.shout_out.build(shout_out_params)
    if @shout_out.save
        flash[:success] = "Shout Out Created"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render user
    end
end

def destroy
end

private

def shout_out_params
    params.require(:shout_out).permit(:content)
end
end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @shoutouts = @user.shout_outs.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @shoutouts.user = User.find(params[:id]).name
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      #handles successful update of account info
      flash[:success] = "Updated Profile Info"
      redirect_to @user
   else
      render 'edit'
   end
 end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,           :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token 
  # :activation_token
  has_many :scrimmages
  has_many :ShoutOuts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :direct_messages, :through => :friendships
  before_save :downcase_email
  # before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  #returns a random token for remember function
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  #returns true if token matches the digest
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end
  #forgets the user
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  private

  # converts emails to downcase
  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end
  #creates and assigns activation token and digest
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end
end
```

micropost model

```
class ShoutOut < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc)}
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: {maximum: 140}
end
```

view partial

```
<li id="shoutout-<%= ShoutOut.id %>">
<%= link_to gravatar_for(ShoutOut.user, size: 50), ShoutOut.user %>
<span class="user"><%= link_to ShoutOut.user.name, ShoutOut.user %></span>
<span class="content"><%= ShoutOut.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(shout_out.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
```

routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # root to: 'users#new'
  # these routes are for showing users a login form, logging them in, and logging them out.
   get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
   post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
   get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  post '/users' => 'users#create'
  post '/users/id/edit' => 'users#edit'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  root to: 'landing#index'
end
```

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZUbO.png)-

Comment: Post the error message please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in the above code which is confusing rails.

1. In the micropost model, you have defined a class called ShoutOut. You may have heard the expression 'convention over configuration'. Rails is looking for the shoutout file. Your ShoutOut class should be in a file called shout_out.rb in the models folder.
2. In the user class, you have put has_many ShoutOuts, it should be has_many :shout_outs
3. I have a feeling the ShoutOutController should be ShoutOutsController, but you will need to post your routes file in order to confirm.
4. In the view partial, why are you calling ShoutOut.id? I suspect you want to use shout_out.id, but you need to post the view that is calling that partial, along with the controller method that is calling the view. In this view you currently only have access to @user variable which is set in the show method in the Users controller.

It looks like you are not clear on why some things should be capitalised and why they shouldn't. Read up on instance vs method variables and on class methods vs instance methods. Try the following in your view

```
<% @user.shoutouts.each do |shout_out| %>
  <li id="shoutout-<%= shout_out.id %>">
    <%= link_to gravatar_for(@user, size: 50), @user %>
    <span class="user"><%= link_to @user.name, @user %></span>
    <span class="content"><%= shout_out.content %></span>
    <span class="timestamp"> Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(shout_out.created_at) %> ago. </span>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

As Joe C commented, you need to post the actual error message along with the stack trace so we can help you debug the error. If you look carefully at the error message, it will give you a file name and line number of where the error is occurring.

Comment: Thank you for your help margo, 1) i do have the file listed as shout_out.rb  2)I have edited the association back to :shout_outs and am still getting the no method error 3) I have posted the routes file above and also screen capd the error and the partial is rending on a User#show and the controller is listed above

Comment: It looks like you dont have an understanding of passing variables from the controller action to use in the view. In Users#show, you are only setting an @user variable so that is the only variable you can use in the show view. You're getting that error because you're using the class Shout and it doesn't have a class method 'id'. I will amend my answer with some code for you to try in the view.

Answer (score -1):

Ty again for helping, but what I've been using is the guide from michael harti linked above and, after a lot of changes this was when i decided to post on Stack. I tried using `User.shout_out` and `User.shoutout` and `User.shout_outs` with the results being the same error. Is the guide wrong?

Comment: I can't comment on the guide, but did you try the code I posted below. Also I dont think you need the 2nd and 3rd lines in the show action of the UsersController.

Comment: I tried the edits you posted above, and i recieved the following error [link](http://imgur.com/a/J7Rhd)  I also tried removing the @user and just leaving user and got the following error with a helper file for the gravatar  [link](http://imgur.com/a/3LJUO).

Comment: again, I urge you to use the information from the error message. It says 2 arguments given, 1 expected. In your link to remove the second argument (size: 50). Re the second one, use @ user and read up how to pass variables from a controller to a view, as per my  comment above.